# PHP inject a class as a dependency instead of instance of a class

Tags: php

Is there any way I can inject a class as a dependency in the constructor, so that in class methods I could do something like this:

```
$item = new $this->item($params);
```

Comment: Is this a [Factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/php/1) that you want injected in the constructor? You use It to make instances of the things that you want?

Comment: Ok, seems like I can just save class name to a string and then call it like new $class_name. But I have to use full class name with namespace.